# How To Monitor Printserver Queues

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, monitoring, printing, print-server

Do you know of any (preferably free) software that will monitor printer queues on a Windows Server 2008 print server?  Specifically, I would like to be able to fire off an alert/email if the queue for a printer is >5 jobs, or if the state of the printer changes. (Offline, Paused, etc)

Thanks!

Josh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this from the Print Management console on W2K8. Go into the Custom Filters section and set up filters and notifications based on your criteria.

Comment: More than happy to help.

Comment: Start->Run "printmanagement.msc"